# PHP header redirection does not work on IE 8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, redirect, header

A redirection under php:

```
header("Location: mask.php")
```

does **work** with IE 9, google chrome, firefox, but **not** with IE 8.

How can I fix this?

PS: `header("Location: http://......")` does not help.

Comment: Always use `exit;` after `header('location:url');`.

Answer (score 7):

You lack `;` at the end end you need to `exit` your script so no script is executed anymore.

```
<?php
    header("Location: mask.php");
    exit; // with die at the end
?>
```

To test on `IE` make a sample page that redirects someplace and test on [NetRenderer](http://netrenderer.com/)

Comment: I tried with exit. No positive effect. Blank screen and no redirection as before. -- I use a session.

Comment: Then it's not from your script, it's from your browser (I mean some browser plugins or toolbars). [Test here](http://netrenderer.com/), choose IE8 ..

Comment: this does not work properly. It shows a blank sreen for my site. However, in reality it shows something (before one presses "enter" in a mask).

Comment: Maybe you send some other invalid headers, maybe you have some scripts that detect `<IE9`, test with a simple script, like the one I've posted.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. PLease see the "solution" I wrote below.

Answer (score 0):

Add `die();` after.

Like:

```
header("Location: mask.php");
die();
```

Comment: Isn't `die()` used for exception throwing, whereas `exit()` is used to interrupt a script?

Comment: I have used exit(); (with brackets). Does not help

Comment: Due to PHP DOCS (http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) `die();` is eqivalent for `exit();`. To throw exceptions we use `throw`. Thanks for downvote Matt.

Comment: I used die() also. No effect.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answers. I added exit. Obviously, "header" is not the problem, but the "input" input. It does not react on "enter", instead, one needs to click the submit button. How can I fix this, such that it works also under IE 8?

Comment: That is another question.  take in consideration one of the two answers and create a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and this post still comes up in Google. The solution that worked for me was to include the www in the URL.

Example:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/mask.php");
exit();
```

Cheers.