# Force download file IN IE

Tags: codeigniter

while download file using codeigniter in IE it redirects image path with out showing any popup like firefox or chrome to download file

code I am using in my controller:

```
public function download_file($filename)
    {         
            $this->load->helper('download'); //load helper
           $data = file_get_contents('wall-images/'.$filename); // Read the file's contents
           $name = $filename;
           force_download($name, $data);    

    }
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056436/php-header-redirection-does-not-work-on-ie-8

Comment: In this link i have found mask.php. May i know what is this file where  can i find this

Answer (score 0):

I use javascript & it works for all browsers.

`<a target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" id="download" href="#">Download File</a>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#download').click(function(){
        var url = "<?php echo site_url($filename); ?>";
        document.location = url;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I came to know where I did mistake, and found solution thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support neither navigating to a data URI nor the `download` attribute.
You can use `navigator.msSaveBlob` to save file for IE 10+.
You can check `window.navigator.msSaveBlob`and write IE specific Code otherwise use existing code to save file.
You can check following link for more details:
[Saving files locally using Blob and msSaveBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx)